# How do I get the last inserted id from a MySQL database table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 'Users' table in my database and when someone makes a new account I want to, instead of doing an auto increment for the id, get the value of the last id inserted, add 1 to it, then insert it with the rest of the create user data. My existing code is:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("db");

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
// ... get all the other info from create user form


$query = "INSERT INTO Users ('fname','lname','email','username','password') 
          VALUES 
          ('$fname','$lname','$email','$username','password')"
```

What I would want to do is get the 'id' from the Users table of the last user (row) in the table, then add 1 to it, and have the code be this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Users ('id','fname','lname','email','username','password') 
VALUES 
('$id','$fname','$lname','$email','$username','$password')";
```

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: Thank you all for caring about me enough to remind me of SQL Injection. The code I provided is a minimal example of what I am doing. I didn't want to put all of it into my example. But thanks anyway

Comment: Watch out SQL Injection. You should escape the input from POST before inserting into SQL

Comment: why are you using phps mysql api? its deprecated... if you use mysqli or pdo you can use the last_insert_id that is supported in their api's

Comment: Yes I know @Raptor. The code I provided isn't exact. It is just a rough sketch of what I have it doing. thanks for the input though

Comment: What is the use of `+1`d value? It sounds wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysql_insert_id();` function:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Users ('fname','lname','email','username','password') 
          VALUES 
          ('$fname','$lname','$email','$username','password')"
$lastid=mysql_insert_id(); /* GET THE ID OF THE INSERT QUERY */
$lastid++; /* INCREMENT THE ID */
```

Some tips for your future:
Use [mysqli prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli). Read more about SQL injections [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: `$newincrementedid` --- what's that?

Comment: @zerkms - You said you wanted to get the last ID, and then increment it by yourself?!

Comment: @zerkms - Ooops.. :P

Comment: As of `+1` - I think it worth making a note that `incremented value + 1` makes no sense. It's like a meaningless info that OP should not use in any way at first place. I agree that you just answered what OP asked, but we're here try to prevent people from doing stupid things.

Comment: For the downvoter, don't be bitter just because the OP accepted my answer than the other answer that you prefer. Not my fault. Thanks :)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `$lastid=$lastid++;` <--- what's that o_O

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `++$lastid`? (it's funny that both answers were affected by the same mistake)

Comment: @LoganWayne I downvoted and i didn't answer... not being bitter and honestly thats a little childish for you to think that.... the reason for the downvote is because you have code in the answer that is not only unnecessary its wrong... your increment is wrong and if its used for another query it will be an incorrect value

Comment: @LoganWayne if you want to have another variable called $lastid then you need to do `$lastid = $lastid + 1;`

Comment: @JohnRuddell I cannot believe `+ 1` is the hardest part of the question :-D

Comment: @zerkms Right??? basic stuff here lol

Comment: `$lastid=++$lastid` --- OH GOD. Seriously, how hard is it to add `1` to an integer?

Comment: @zerkms #redundantcode

Comment: Guys, my first answer was just a simple `$newid=$lastid+1;`, then @zerkms didn't like it. So I changed and made it worse. Don't worry. I'll delete my answer and hang myself. Thanks

Comment: @LoganWayne i don't know why a downvote matters that much to you... I removed my downvote because you now have a correct answer as opposed to an incorrect answer. even though it was changed from our responses... its just a website. dont freakout about a simple downvote, its a part of life... sometimes theres negatives and sometimes positives its a part of life. We all learn from it and grow

Comment: "then @zerkms didn't like it" --- I'm sorry? I didn't "didn't like" your implementation in particular, I didn't like the whole idea of modifying an autoincrement value overall

Answer (score 3):

1. mysql_insert_id()

   ```
   mysql_query("INSERT QUERY ...");
   $id = mysql_insert_id();
   ```
2. Use mysqli instead (or PDO).

   ```
   $mysqli->query($query);
   $id = $mysqli->insert_id
   printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $id);
   ```
3. Escape properly! Because you are vulnerable to SQL injection.
4. increment: `$lastid = $lastid + 1;` or just `$id++`.

   The auto-increment is there for a reason. Use it.

Comment: `$new_id = $id++;` --- it won't work as you think (that's why immutability rocks)

Comment: how do you know what i think? :) mindreader?

Comment: I know the question and I can read the variable names. `$new_id` will not be a new value, but the old. So if `$id = 1`, then after that statement `new_id = 1, id = 2`. Is that what you **really expected** or I've read your minds correctly?

Comment: Does $id++ give the value before the increment?  Or does he need ++$id?  I always get confused.

Comment: @johnny follow the order `$id++` == `return value, then ++`. `++$id` == `++, then return value`

Comment: he should just increment the id and forget the new_id... aka just use $id with ++$id or to keep his syntax just say `$new_id = $id + 1;`

Comment: roger that. changed to pre-increment. my fault.

Comment: Now it's time to make a note that `$new_id` now is a meaningless value. It cannot be used for anything since you cannot trust it.

Comment: I guess I"m not sure what he means by incrementing, as in which way does he want it.  Before or after.

Comment: @zerkms hence my comment... drop new_id or make new_id = $id + 1

Comment: Nevermind. The other answer got accepted, so he likes `$last=$lastid++;`.